# How to stick Dired-mode buffer to a separate frame in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, frame, dired

I want files navigation via dired to be made in a separate frame but all files to be open in another frame. So how can I stick dired-mode buffers to a standalone-frame? Thanks.

I am interested in solution w/o using extra-packages.

Comment: To run dired in a different frame, just run `C-x 5 d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something like this in your init file (`.emacs`):

```
    (defadvice dired (after dedicate activate)
      "Make this Dired window dedicated."
      (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t))
```

That makes Dired's window be dedicated, meaning that it cannot be reused for another buffer.  You can do the same thing for other Dired commands -- e.g. `dired-other-window`.